# Smps connecting negative output to earth ground

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, grounding

I design a circuit and I need a 3A 12V power supply and want to use a 40W myrra smps but the datasheet mentions this :
[image: myrra 47 series]

Now I need to connect the (-) output to GND of the circuit and to Earth Ground (PE). Why would that be a problem since the outputs are isolated from the inputs?

Comment: If it is isolated you can do this. Maybe add the datasheet for others to review it anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing the dodgy quality of the datasheet I interpret their sketch as this:

You are not allowed to have *no* connection to GND.

However if you definitely *need* GND isolation (you don't), then you still must connect the caps to GND as shown.

**Context:** As Kartman stresses, for EMC reasons you must always provide a low impedance RF shunt from the DC output to the AC input. The last image suggests that the converter already has internal Y caps from AC to GND, so you must only provide an RF shunt from the DC side to GND. This means either bonding DC to GND (as you plan to do), or using a capacitor to connecto DC to GND.

Comment: Thanks, I can see now that it seems to be a matter of interpretation. It really seemed strange as I have never seen that kind of restriction on any of the other SMPS's I've considered for the design. (I've chose this as it's the smallest supply that fits the budget. I hope it won't come back and bite me)

Comment: The transformer has inter-winding capacitance, so for EMC compliance that capacitance needs to be shunted. Even the cheapy phone chargers will have a Y capacitor.